# Multiselect in list or datagrid

Tags: admin-on-rest

Is there any way currently to select items and apply an action on multiple items in a list or datagrid?

Datagrid has options for selecting items even multiselect but i can only manage to get the relative indexes of the items in the current list not the data objects.

I could create an action to lookup up the items given the index and then store it in redux state and later apply the action. But it feels very prone to errors passing around array indexes.

If i could choose the datagrid would have a selectedRows callback that passed back the full dataitems, dispatching an action on the item id's would then be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature isn't implemented yet, but a Pull Request is open about selectable / bulk actions.

https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/pull/1241